# OperationFailedException when using vNext template in Microsoft Release Management

Tags: visual-studio-2013, release-management, ms-release-management

I am getting the following error while running a workflow in microsoft release management 2013 update 4:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Release.Common.Helpers.OperationFailedException: System.AggregateException: Failed to install 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployerbd3a8a59-325a-45d0-89f5-86a548554a12' from service executable path VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe . Consult the logs below:
c:\Users\vmadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\mfurnl9w.0.cs(95) : ; expected

c:\Users\vmadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\mfurnl9w.0.cs(94) :                     IntPtr policyHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

c:\Users\vmadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\mfurnl9w.0.cs(95) : >>>                     var attributes = new LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES()

c:\Users\vmadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\mfurnl9w.0.cs(96) :
```

I am using a vNext Release Template. I have added an action "Deploy using PS/DSC" which is supposed to execute a powershell script on the machine.
All I get is the above error.

I have verified that remoting is setup as per here (on-premise section): https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/deploy-no-agents-vs.aspx

I have also referenced this: http://roadtoalm.com/2015/02/04/start-with-visual-studio-release-management-vnextvs-rm-for-dummies/
but our error is slightly different as it doesn't complain about the account. Although i am assuming the account is ok... I did use a couple variations and when the account is incorrect i get an obvious failure.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using an account with appropriate credentials in your deployment action?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using a domain account, and a local account on that destination VM and each account had admin access on the machine. There is only one hit in all of Google that actually references VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe so it is really hard to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question because I had the same issue. In RoadToAlm article he is using Windows Server 2012 on his VM. My Azure VM was Windows Server 2008 SP2 and I resolved the issue by installing Windows Management Framework 3.0 (http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9811175) which includes a newer Powershell than was installed on my server. After this update the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue on a destination Windows Server 2008 R2. I just shift down the UAC level and it let the deployment tools be copied by the task into the c:\Windows\DtlDownloads folder (with VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe).

From the moment this file was available, the artifact copy had been successful.